# N54 335i BMW coolant leak and oil in coolant reservoir

Tags: bmw

I got a low coolant light pop up, i checked the reservoir and it was almost empty and there was little bits of brown foam (guessing its oil). I filled it up with distilled water and bmw coolant (originally had bmw coolant). noticed leaking on the passenger side of car at first when i was out but in my garage, i saw a leak behind the engine, like in the middle of the car. any guesses? where is it leaking that oil can get in it?

car is awd automatic 335i 2009

Answer (score 3):

If there is Oil in the water it could be from a blown head gasket, or possibly a crack in the block or head. Is there any water on the oil? it tends to form a light coloured sludge if there is.